# Template Abtract Class has Value in Dictionary

Tags: c#, templates, design-patterns, data-structures, abstract-class

Here are my class

```
Abstract Class - AbstractManager<T>
Class - SettingsManager : AbstractManager<Settings>
Class - Settings
Class - LoginManager : AbstractManager<Login>
Class - Login
Enum - Managers
Class - ManagersAccessPoint
```

ManagersAccessPoint needs to have a Dictionnary to map from an Enum to a Manager.

```
_dict : Dictionary<Managers, AbstractManager<T>>
```

Problem is, I don`t want ManagersAccessPoint to be templated either to Settings or to Login.
I want to have both in it and use it ''transparently''

```
_dict : Dictionary<Managers, AbstractManager>
```

would be what I need, but it is not ok to write that.

How should I do this?

Comment: Because you don't have an *AbstractManager* interface/base class. You have the generic type *AbstractManager<T>* (side note: it is not! a template, it is a Generic) and the concrete types *AbstractManager<Settings>* and *AbstractManager<Login>*, which cannot be cast to each others type. Create an *AbstractManager* interface, and let *AbstractManager<T>* derive from that interface (as an example, look at the *System.Collections.Generic.List<T>*, which implements *ICollection<T>* which in turn derives from *IEnumerable*)

Comment: I'll try that soon and see if it fits my need :) 
Thank you

Comment: @elgonzo That is a great answer. Post it.

Comment: It seems good, but i was wondering if doing so ''blocks'' me from having a method that would have the following header : public void Load(T objToload) where T is the templated type into my abstract manager

BTW please add as answer, i will accept it

Comment: You should really add it up has an answer

Comment: You can add generic methods to ManagersAccessPoint that will operate on the right type of AbstractManager to do things like Load(T objToload).

Answer (score 0):

Scrap that enum and focus on getting the manager for a specify entity type.

your problem is that the base class is typed, which means that it's impossible to add to a general list (as it's not typed). Hence what you need to do is to put it in a object list and cast it to the correct type when requested.

```
public class ManagersAccessPoint
{
  private Dictionary<Type, object> _items : Dictionary<Type, object>();

  public void Register<TEntity>(AbstractManager<TEntity> manager)
  {
      _items[typeof(TEntity)] = manager;
  }

  public AbstractManager<TEntity> Get<TEntity>()
  {
      return (AbstractManager<TEntity>)_items[typeof(TEntity)];
  }
}
```

As you see, within the implementation nothing is typed.

Example:

```
//registration
var accessPoint = new ManagersAccessPoint();
accessPoint.Register(new SettingsManager());
accessPoint.Register(new LoginManager());


//usage
var manager = accessPoint.Get<Login>();
manager.blabla();
```

Even without the enum, there is no connection between the actual manager implementation and the entity itself.